# Notepad++ connecting to Ubuntu 12.04 AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, notepad++

Notepad++ gives me this error, while I'm trying to connect to using sftp to my aws ec2 


[NppFTP] Everything initialized
Connecting
[SFTP] Host key accepted
[SFTP] Error during authentication: Invalid private key file.
Unable to connect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My mistake was that I was using the certificate with extension *.ppk that I use with putty.
The problem was solved when I changed it for the *.pem extension.
Hope my solution helps you.

Comment: Is there any other settings that need to be updated for this to work?  I am using Notepad++ on Windows 7 and point the authentication to my .pem file, but get "Unable to authenticate".  Thanks!

Comment: Disregard my previous comment - I still needed to provide my username and then I was able to connect